# Sometimes I am born in silence

Tags: riddle

Sometimes I am born in silence,
Other times, no.
I am unseen,
But I make my presence known.
In time, I fade without a trace.
I harm no one,
but I am unpopular with all.

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are a

> fart

Sometimes I am born in silence,

> There can be silent farts.

Other times, no.

> There can be noisy farts.

I am unseen,

> No one can see a fart.

But I make my presence known.

> Farts can smell.

In time, I fade without a trace.

> The smell fades away over time.

I harm no one,

> Farts are not harmful.

but I am unpopular with all.

> No one likes a fart.

Comment: You solved this one lightning fast +1

Comment: @MichaelRize perhaps pacoverflow has lots of experience in this field.