# I am known for my silence

Tags: riddle

> I am known for my silence,
>
> But I can also be kind of loud.
>
> I can be found throughout the world,
>
> But I cannot be found naturally.
>
> I am voiceless,
>
> Yet I am voiced everyday.
>
> I begin at the back and make my way forward.

**What am I?**

Hint 1

> I am used for communication.

Hint 2

> My use is demonstrated within this riddle.

Hint 3

> The first two lines give me away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sometimes I am born in silence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/sometimes-i-am-born-in-silence)

Comment: Nope. This might be too broad though, I will add another line.

Comment: Sounds good -- thanks very much for your quick response! I will retract my vote.

Comment: Are you a fart?

Comment: @filip heheh *silent, but deadly* :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> The letter K?

I am known for my silence,

> The silent K in KNOWN

But I can also be kind of loud.

> The loud K in KIND

I can be found throughout the world,

> K's are used in all sorts of languages around the world.

But I cannot be found naturally.

> It's a human constructed letter/sound used to mean something.

I am voiceless,

> Letters can't talk. Also, from @jafe, K is a voiceless consonant. (Thanks, @jafe!!)

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> People say the letter K every day.

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> The letter K starts at the back of the throat when you say it (the kuh sound) and comes forward through the mouth (the ayy sound).

Hints:

> Used for communication 
>  **Yes, letters are used for communication** 
>  My use is demonstrated within this riddle. 
>  **Yes, Ks are used in this riddle** 
>  The first two lines give me away. 
>  **They do, because of the different sounds that the hard and silent Ks make in the first two lines.**

Comment: As for line 5, rot13[x vf n ibvpryrff pbafbanag] :)

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Achmed the dead terrorist?

I am known for my silence,

> He is known for shouting "SILENCE! I KILL YOU!"

But I can also be kind of loud

> He is known for **shouting** "SILENCE! I KILL YOU!"

I can be found throughout the world,

> Jeff Dunham, the ventriloquist, probably went around the world with Achmed after he went viral.

But I cannot be found naturally.

> Achmed is a manmade ventriloquist puppet

I am voiceless,

> He does not have his own voice

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Jeff practices Achmed's voice every day.

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> As with all ventriloquist-puppets, the ventriloquist's hand enters throught it's back where it has to make it's way forward until it reaches the face

Comment: I love this answer! +1

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> AN OPINION?

I am known for my silence,

> Most people form silent opinions about other people or issues.

But I can also be kind of loud.

> Some people's opinions are vocal.

I can be found throughout the world,

> Everybody has opinions.

But I cannot be found naturally.

> They're constructs of animals' (especially humans') thoughts.

I am voiceless,

> Opinions can't speak for themselves.

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Lots of people enjoy voicing their opinions every day.

Comment: Good guess, I have added another line to make it less broad.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> a flag?

I am known for my silence,

But I can also be kind of loud.

> Flags are physically silent but visually vibrant in colour

I can be found throughout the world,

But I cannot be found naturally.

> Collections of people everywhere represent themselves with flags, but they are a wholly human creation.

I am voiceless,

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Flags themselves are meaningless without context (therefore have no voice), but people speak on their behalf in many contexts. The Pledge of Allegiance is an excellent example of giving a flag a voice.

Comment: Very clever. I have added another line to make it less broad.

Comment: Technically, when my word flaps in the wind, the "wave" begins at the back and makes its way forward :P

Answer (score 3):

Are you, perhaps:

> Radio

I am known for my silence:

> Radio silence is a term for not communicating

But I can also be kind of loud:

> Yep, especially if one turns it up to 11

I can be found throughout the world:

> Check (even in Antarctica)

But I cannot be found naturally:

> Radio waves do occur naturally (lightning / some stars & other astronomical objects) but radio itself does not

I am voiceless:

> It is a medium and so has no voice of its own

Yet I am voiced everyday:

> By amplification of a select part of the modulated signal we can listen to all sorts of news, opinion and entertainment on the "wireless"

I begin at the back and make my way forward:

> Radio broadcasts are transmitted using radio waves which are a band of electromagnetic radiation, which propagate (forward?) through space-time.

Comment: Obligatory: [_These go up to_ ___ELEVEN___](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xgx4k83zzc)

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> "."?

I am known for my silence,

> While reading a "." you aren't saying anything

But I can also be kind of loud.

> A "." can be found in an "!"

I can be found throughout the world,

> Almost all languages use "." to finish their sentences

But I cannot be found naturally.

> Languages are still a human construct, "." is therefore also one

I am voiceless,

> Again, it isn't "read" in a sentence

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Sentences are used in any language, so are "."s

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> Every sentence is finished with a "."

Hints:

I am used for communication.

> Communication = Language

My use is demonstrated within this riddle.

> "."s are used on every second line of the riddle

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> READING? (Or possibly THINKING?)

I am known for my silence,

> As in, silent reading. (Thinking is also silent)

But I can also be kind of loud.

> You can read out loud/for storytime. (As in thinking out loud)

I can be found throughout the world,

> People all around the world know how to read. (And they think all the time)

But I cannot be found naturally.

> Nobody "naturally" knows how to read things. (Nobody "naturally" knows how to think, this skill is developed over time)

I am voiceless,

> Reading has no voice. (Neither does thinking)

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> When you read something, you often voice opinions based on what you've read. (You also voice your thoughts)

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> The back/top of the page towards the front/end of the page? (The back of the skull to the front? Or the vocal cords to the mouth?)

The hints:

> I am used for communication. 
>  **Reading is an important part of communication. (So is thinking)** 
>  My use is demonstrated within this riddle. 
>  **We had to read the riddle in order to solve it. (We also had to think to solve it)**

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The common man? (ideology)

I am known for my silence,

> Underrepresented, unseen, practically unnoticeable.

But I can also be kind of loud.

> Strikes, unions, rallies, etc.

But I cannot be found naturally.

> Middle class has to be created, because society tends to build up a more feudal based society.

I am voiceless,

> Alone, the common man can do nothing.

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Socialist Parties.

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> True in most aspects of common man ideology. You start at the bottom and you work your way to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Writings (Paragraphs/Text/English)

I am known for my silence,

> Writings don't make noises

But I can also be kind of loud.

> But can create discussions

I can be found throughout the world,

> Everyone uses them all over the world

But I cannot be found naturally.

> But was created by people

I am voiceless,

> Literally has no voices (no sound)

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Used to voice opinions

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> You start reading it from the top to bottom or left to right (Maybe back to forward implies that?)

Comment: Incorrect, but you're heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The letter "H"

I am known for my silence,

> Often "dropped" in many words, dialects and languages

But I can also be kind of loud.

> HA!

I can be found throughout the world,

> Pretty much everyone uses the "h" sound

But I cannot be found naturally.

> ?

I am voiceless,

> "H" is an "unvoiced" consonant

Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Used in so many words

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> Sound beings in the back of the throat and moves towards the front

The hints:

> I am used for communication: As are all letters
>  My use is demonstrated within this riddle: The letter h is used here

Comment: You're very close!

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Electricity?

I am known for my silence,
But I can also be kind of loud

> Usually works silently, but when an instrument bursts, it can make a loud sound. Or can be thought of as speakers.

I can be found throughout the world,
But I cannot be found naturally.

> Used around the world, but can only be generated by artificial means

I am voiceless,
Yet I am voiced everyday.

> Electricity by itself has no voice. But is used for talking on phones, VOIP etc.

I begin at the back and make my way forward.

> Maybe you can say it makes its way from behind the screen to on the screen/UI for things like desktops and phones

And the title

> Electric cars and vehicles are known to be much more silent than others